# Regex with characters and numbers in no particular order (but limited to 10 numbers max)

Tags: regex

So i have a string (with spaces):

```
John Doe
```

That can be mixed with up to 10 numbers

```
John Doe 123456789
```

In no particular order:

```
1234john Doe567890
```

I've tried mixing chars, spaces and numbers like this:

```
([A-Za-z ])([0-9]){10}
```

But i doesn't hit the target

How can i write a Regex to validate that?

Comment: Try `^(?:[A-Za-z ]*[0-9]){0,10}[A-Za-z ]*$`. If there must be at least 1 digit, try ``^(?:[A-Za-z ]*[0-9]){1,10}[A-Za-z ]*$``

Comment: Regular expressions are for pattern matching. By definition, that means there must be a pattern that can be matched. Your data has no pattern. Regexes don't count things the way you want them counted.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew works like a charm! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
^(?=(?:\D*\d){0,10}\D*$)
```

Explained:

```
 ^                   # Beginning of string, BOS

 # Lookahead assertion
 (?=
      # Note this group is designed 
      # so that it is the only place
      # a digit can exist.

      (?:                 # Group
           \D*                 #  Optional, any amount of non-digits
           \d                  #  Required, a single digit
      ){0,10}             # End group, do 0 to 10 times

      # Example:
      #   - If this group runs 0 times, no digits were in the string.
      #   - If this group runs 4 times, 4 digits are in the string.
      #   - Therefore, min digits = 0, max digits = 10

      \D*                 # Finally, and optionally, any amount of non-digits
      $                   # End of string, EOS
 )
```

Comment: Could you explain how this works? [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22412543).

Comment: @WaiHaLee - sure.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
^(?:[A-Za-z ]*[0-9]){0,10}[A-Za-z ]*$
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[A-Za-z ]*[0-9]){0,10}` - zero to ten occurrences of

  - `[A-Za-z ]*` - 0 or more spaces or letters
  - `[0-9]` - a digit
- `[A-Za-z ]*` - 0 or more spaces or letters
- `$` - end of string.

If there must be at least 1 digit, use

```
^(?:[A-Za-z ]*[0-9]){1,10}[A-Za-z ]*$
                     ^
```